# setting up a default value of a column in select statement

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange

actually i have 2 tables table1 and table2

table1

```
name
city
addr.
```

table2

```
name
city
addr.
ph.no
```

now ph.no field is an extra field in table 2

so i want to show field ph.no with a default value of 12345 in the output of select query on table1 as i want to append that output into an outfile.
help me out ..I am using db2 as400 database

Comment: We need to know the definition of ph.no before we can tell how any default might work. E.g., if it allows NULLs, it can be very different from NOT NULL. DEFAULT attribute, data type and size are also needed.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, you can do this:

```
SELECT name, city, addr, 12345 AS ph_no
FROM table1
```

Comment: I need t show `ph_no` as `12345` when `name` is `jhon` and `ph_no` as `123` when `name` is `peter` . Is it possible ?

Comment: @NimmagaddaGowtham, use `case when`.

Answer (score 3):

I know this thread is very old but in case someone needs an answer to Nimmagadda's question, you should be able to accomplish it with something along the lines of:

```
SELECT name, city, addr, 
CASE name 
  WHEN 'john' THEN 12345 
  WHEN 'peter' THEN 123 
  ELSE 0 /* ???? */ END AS ph_no
FROM table1
```